# How can I check programmatically if a drive is subject to system restore feature in windows?

Tags: windows, system-restore

As the title tells, I need a programmatic way to find out if a particular disk drive is subject to System Restore in Windows. 
You may see this information in `Control Panel/System/System protection` tab.

I'm developing a security-related app for windows, and it is crucial that some of its internal files are present strictly in a single copy. I'd like to prevent this files from being inadvertently copied/backed up by windows. Or at least to warn the user of the ensuing security risk.

I know of the 
`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\BackupRestore\FilesNotToBackup` but it doesn't solve the problem because it is used only at the restore phase, and the file contents is still present in the backup storage.

There is also `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SystemRestore`, but it doesn't contain information about subject disks, at least I don't see it.

Any clues are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System restore is managed by the [Volume Shadow Copy api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/vss/volume-shadow-copy-reference).

You need to call the [QueryVolumesSupportedForDiffAreas method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/vsmgmt/nf-vsmgmt-ivssdifferentialsoftwaresnapshotmgmt-queryvolumessupportedfordiffareas) and inside the  returned IVssEnumMgmtObject will be a [VSS_DIFF_VOLUME_PROP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/c4a20583-7fee-4ae1-97ed-d80b2a7539e3) structure which will tell you if any storage area is reserved in the m_llVolumeTotalSpace parameter.

Alternatively you could parse the output of the `vssadmin list shadowstorage`command , or its equivalent in Powershell/WMI  by exploring the `Get-CimClass -ClassName *shadow` command.  These commands correspond to wmiobjects and the wmi api which may be easier to use and more accessible depending on your background and programming environment.

---

Also consider using the [`FilesNotToSnapshot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/backup/registry-keys-for-backup-and-restore#filesnottosnapshot) instead of `FilesNotToBackup`. It is the one used for VSS/System Restore. You should [read this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/VSS/excluding-files-from-shadow-copies) on its usage and also an api that lets you exclude files, and take note particularly about the cases where it might not work as you intend.